# What documents should I submit after refusal of a visit visa?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

[image][image]

I am an overseas foreign worker in HK from the Philippines. I applied for a visitor visa and my employer is funding the trip. I have not submitted payslips, only my contract which states the salary amount, my bank book, passport, my employer’s supporting letter plus his tax return to show his financial capacity. However, it is not uncommon in HK for domestic helpers to receive salary in cash, hence there is no entry in my passbook showing the flow of income. In my passbook my employer has transferred a significant amount to fund my trip.

I am fully aware there is no way I can afford the trip just based on my salary. The only reason I am going is clearly because it will be funded 100%. How do I prove that this is genuine? That such money is solely for the trip?

Also, apart from my obvious job in HK, to which I will without doubt be going back to, how else do I prove that I have all intentions of leaving the UK at the end of my specified trip?

Comment: Are you traveling to the UK with your employer to do domestic work, or by yourself for vacation?

Comment: @dda The decision seems like a straight-up provenance of funds issue, but yeah, a refusal notice that says you're going strictly for tourism and it will be paid for entirely by your employer is going to raise some red flags to me, and I'd assume to an ECO, because employers don't normally send their employees on all expenses paid overseas vacations. If the OP is going to work, there's [a visa category for that](https://www.gov.uk/domestic-workers-in-a-private-household-visa), and the answer will be "go do that instead."

Comment: I am going on vacation by myself which is why getting the private household helper visa is not an option. I get the suspicion that it arouses considering the circumstance but I am genuinely going on a holiday funded by my boss. What I really need to know is what documents can I provide to address the refusal decision? I managed to get a Shengen Visa last year and apparently that doesn’t  have any bearing in terms of considering my immigration history.

Comment: Was your Schengen visa for a holiday as well? If so, did your boss fund that in the same way? I ask because you might have submitted better evidence for that one. For the UK visa, your boss could provide a letter saying the money is a salary bonus. That would still be unusually generous for domestic helpers though.

Comment: Yes it was as well for holiday reasons and my employer did helped me with the trip. The documents were just the same, my bankbook with the funds and supporting letter and contract. Only difference would be the additional return ticket, chopped hotel accommodation and cover letter because they were specifically required by the German embassy. Whereas, the UK site specifically tells you that those things will not be considered so therefore you must not submit those. I find it tricky.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at our question [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab), which explains what the UK is looking for in your bank statements. You'll see your case discussed under "funds parking."

To start, pay stubs documenting that you are regularly paid in cash will help demonstrate your income. Your employer could also provide documentation that they've paid you a 40,000HKD bonus.

That said, it's going to be difficult to convince the ECO that your employer has paid you a bonus of nearly eight months of your salary so you can take an overseas vacation, as that will likely strike them as unusual.

Comment: @ZackLipton.  Thank you, I have thought exactly the same - pay stubs and documentation from my employer regarding the funds. Just wondering what else can I send to demonstrate that it is simply a case of Person A not having the means to travel on holiday and so another Person B with the means is making it happen for Person A. It may strike them as unusual but is not illegal nor impossible at all - how do you demonstrate and prove that though?  I do not want to re-apply until I have considered all possible documents to affirm my application otherwise, I will expectedly just be refused again.☹️

Comment: Something doesn't have to be Illegal or impossible to get your visa refused. It's up to you to demonstrate that everything is in order.